# How to allow file uploading outside home directory with SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm running a Fedora 8 Core server. SSH is enabled and I can login with Transmit (FTP client) on port 22. When logged in, I can successfully upload files to the users home directory. Outside the home directory I can only browse files, not upload/change anything. How can I allow file uploading to a specific directory outside the users home directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an easy method is to grant the user rights to the folder you want them to be able to upload to, then add a symlink (link -s) from their home folder to the destination.

You can also just use

```
scp file user@server:/path
```

which will let you upload to any directory you have permissions to

- file is the file to copy
- user & server should be obvious
- /path is any destination path on the server which you have rights to; so /home/user/ would be your likely default home folder

Comment: You also have to set the executable bit on all containing folders (see answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/866283/why-cant-i-cd-into-a-directory-with-a-user-not-owner-group)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make those directories writable by the proper users, or (easier) that user's group. This is of course a huge security hole, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

HI,
Give the FTP user write permission on the directory where you want to upload your files.